# Problems installing rails on Ubuntu 12.04. Rails gems library is empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I got some problem installing rails on Ubuntu 12.04. I have rails working on my Ubuntu for a little time. But for some reason I uninstall rails. When I decided to install it again with `sudo gem install rails` . The command `rails -v` doesn't work. When I run the command `sudo gem install rails` there is no error occurring just a message that saying:

`Successfully installed rails-3.2.6`

I look at the folder `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.2.6` and it is completely empty?

I wonder how I can fix this problem?

Comment: See my answer below, I would have put it in a comment, but a bit too much text. It's what I use on new OpenVZ Container VMs in my Private Cloud for hosting Ruby on Rails servers.

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling it, then running a cleanup, deleting that folder, and trying again?

Answer (score 0):

below is my openvz container script for Ubuntu Server 12.04. It should work with desktop version as well. It downloads and installs a bunch of updates and dependencies. A lot of it can be stripped out if you are not using this as a production environment, but it seems to work well for me even in a devel environment.

It will install the latest Ruby, Gems, Ruby on Rails, Passenger

```
sudo su
```

> apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install
>   libopenssl-ruby build-essential nano libmagic-dev coffeescript
>   zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev libssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev ntp ntpdate
>   apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-doc apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils
>   libexpat1 ssl-cert libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-gd
>   php5-mysql php5-imap php5-cli php5-cgi libapache2-mod-fcgid
>   apache2-suexec php-pear php-auth php5-mcrypt mcrypt php5-imagick
>   imagemagick libapache2-mod-suphp libcurl4-openssl-dev
>   apache2-prefork-dev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev 
>   libmagick-dev git-core git-gui git-doc libreadline-dev -y && a2enmod
>   suexec rewrite ssl actions include && a2enmod dav_fs dav auth_digest
>   && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart && wget
>   http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz && tar
>   zxf ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz && cd ruby-1.9.3-p194 && ./configure &&
>   make && make install && gem update --system && gem install rails &&
>   gem install passenger && passenger-install-apache2-module